# What Google hosting should I choose for a Node.js and React website?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I want to be able to host my website on google servers, i would like to design the website using react along with node js in the backend, from my current research it seems that google app engine is the way to go.
Am i on the right path or should i be looking at another avenue.I don't expect the site to intake a lot of traffic so a low cost plan would be ideal, a free plan would be amazing if possible if possible.
I also read that google dns could be used for a website which seems pretty convenient, how exactly do i go about this?

Comment: Around the industry, a static website is just a pure HTML one (usually generated by Jekyll or something similar). Your's is a dynamic one, since it has Node.js as a backend. I edited your title question to better reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right path. Goole app engine flexible environment is the ideal choice for you. Since you want your backend to run in Nodejs it's very simple to run Nodejs in Google app engine. Google also give you free $300 for the free trial and you can use it for 12 months.

Read more about the pricing in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing)

Read more about Nodejs in Google app engine flexible [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/)

Comment: Except standard env is far from the ideal choice in this case as nodejs is only supported on the flexible env, which doesn't have a daily free quota like the standard env.

Comment: To clarify a bit...  If you've never been a paying customer of Google Cloud Platform or signed up for the free trial you're eligible for a $300 credit that can be used on any GCP product.  1 vCPU per hour, 1GB memory per hour, and 10GB of persistent disk will run you close to $50/month, however.  That might be a bit steep for what you're planning to do so you should consider the investment in time to move this application to something else if it becomes too expensive after the credit is gone.